# Are all 60 watt apple magsafe adapters compatable?

Tags: magsafe

I have a 60 watt apple magsafe adapter with serial number A1184. There are a good number of other 60 watt adapters produced by apple that appear to have similar hardware, but I'm not sure if they're compatible. Are there any issues using another part, or will only an exact match do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the 60-watt ones yes. But some systems require an 85-watt. Make sure you're buying/using the right one.